# How to setup a reverse proxy on several ports (tcp & udp)

Tags: apache, nginx, proxy, reverse, ports

I have setup a reverse proxy for the website, and now I want to proxy my game server aswell with the ports stated below, but I realy can't find anywhere how to perform this. Does anyone have an idea?
I would like to do this if possible on apache. Am running on ubuntu.

**RDP**

TCP Port: 3389

**MSSQL**

TCP Port: 1143

**TEAMSPEAK**

UDP Port: 9987 
TCP Port: 9987 
TCP Port: 10011 
TCP Port: 30033

**LOGIN SERVER**

TCP Port: 15001
TCP Port: 15100

**GAMESERVER**

TCP Port: 15221

**FTP**

21

Comment: Are you looking for what: forward proxy (which Nginx is not designed for) or TCP reverse proxy (stream module)? Maybe you just need a port forwarding?

Answer (score 6):

Apache is not an ideal tool for proxying TCP connections.
Nginx <strike>plus</strike> [can do it](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/tcp-load-balancing/) <strike>but it's not free</strike>.

What you want is a proxy server like [squid](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/squid.html) which is very well documented.

You can also do this without extra software, just with IP tables as explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/542393/acting-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-raw-tcp-packets/542414#542414).

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 1111 -j DNAT --to-destination ip:port
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 1112 -j DNAT --to-destination ip:port
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 1113 -j DNAT --to-destination ip:port
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

Comment: Stream module is not Plus exclusive feature, it is available in open source version as well: http://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_core_module.html

Comment: I just wanted to add that in addition to adding the iptables rules described here, you may also need to enable IP forwarding. To check if IP forwarding is enabled, run `sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward`, which returns 0 if disabled, 1 if enabled. You can enable it with `sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`, and you can edit /etc/sysctl.conf if you want this to persist across reboots.

See https://fabianlee.org/2018/09/17/ubuntu-using-iptables-to-forward-tcp-and-udp-requests/ for more info.

Comment: But using nginx can you run a website and this proxypass stream both on port 443 for instance?