# apache proxy tcp traffic

Tags: apache, tcp, proxy

I have a weird problem.

I have http traffic coming in on port 80 that is managed by my vhosts file to proxy to internal web servers but I also have tcp non http traffic coming in on port 80 that needs to be proxied to another internal server on port 80.

I have tried to use proxypass but all that did was proxy http traffic just fine but didnt work on the non http traffic.

I have tried mod rewrite rules to try and isolate the source ip address of the non http traffic and create a rule to proxy it to my other internal host but that didnt work either.

I am using windows with apache and would prefer to use apache to achieve this if possible.

Answer (score 2):

As per this Stack overflow thread- Apache is not an ideal tool for proxying TCP connections.
[StackOverlow-how-to-setup-a-reverse-proxy-on-several-ports-tcp-udp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32619379/how-to-setup-a-reverse-proxy-on-several-ports-tcp-udp)